# Conducting linear correlation based on stacked raster in R?

Tags: raster, r

I am analyzing average annual GPP during 2000-2014 of a area. I want to conduct linear correlation analysis between annual GPP and time, and I also want to get the slope and correlation coefficient values of the linear relationship of each cell and output the results as rasters.

Do you know how to calculate the slope and R^2 values in "raster" package in R?

Can calc() or lm () will make it?

I list the data as following:

```
library(raster)
GPP2000=raster("GPP2000.tif")
GPP2001=raster("GPP2001.tif")
GPP2002=raster("GPP2002.tif")
GPP2003=raster("GPP2003.tif")
GPP2004=raster("GPP2004.tif")
GPP2005=raster("GPP2005.tif")
GPP2006=raster("GPP2006.tif")
GPP2007=raster("GPP2007.tif")
GPP2008=raster("GPP2008.tif")
GPP2009=raster("GPP2009.tif")
GPP2010=raster("GPP2010.tif")
GPP2011=raster("GPP2011.tif")
GPP2012=raster("GPP2012.tif")
GPP2013=raster("GPP2013.tif")
GPP2014=raster("GPP2014.tif")
GPP=stack(GPP2000,GPP2001,GPP2002,GPP20003,GPP2004,GPP2005,GPP2006,GPP2007,GPP2008,GPP20009,GPP2010,GPP2011,GPP2012,GPP2013,GPP2014)
```

Comment: There's precisely an example of that in the help page of `raster::calc()`. See `# regression of values in one brick (or stack) with 'time'`. Also note that `stack()` can take a list of filenames as argument so that you don't need to import each layer with `raster()`

Answer (score 5):

Just copying the code snippet of the `raster::calc()` help page.

```
library(raster)

# Create test RasterStack
r <- raster(ncols=36, nrows=18)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
s <- stack(r, r*2, sqrt(r))

# regression of values in one brick (or stack) with 'time'
time <- 1:nlayers(s)
fun <- function(x) { lm(x ~ time)$coefficients[2] }
x2 <- calc(s, fun)
```

To get slope and r.squared, you'd need to adapt the function a little

```
fun2 <- function(x) { model <- summary(lm(x ~ time)); c(model$coefficients[2,1], model$r.squared) }
x2 <- calc(s, fun2)
```

Comment: I have a stack of 21 layers and I applied this exact function to it and I am getting an error:
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function

any clue about what I am doing wrong?